# how to close open html tags automatically with php?

Tags: php, html

I developed many sites on php and mysql.
I have a problem on fetching certain words like i use

```
SELECT *,left('<field>',200) from < table >
```

I got the problem on layout of whole website due to no closing of opened tags.
any suggestion would be great.

I used `strip_tags()` and then `substr()` to crop text.
but i need a permanent solution.

**update**

```
<?php
$fragment = '<p>What a mighty fine <a href="blah">da';
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($fragment,array('show-body-only'=>true),'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
?>
```

enable `php_tidy extension` in localhost through php.ini and it works.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question or give us some code and output.

Comment: I don't understand you question.

Comment: If you're using `strip_tags()` you'll have no HTML tags left to close, no?

Comment: @BoltClock strip_tags() is a palliative. He wants to close opened tags. It's very common task, I can't believe noone understand it

Comment: So you want to select the first 200 characters of textual contents, right?

Comment: the mysql query has nothing to do with html tags

Comment: i used tidy and it worked great. thanks for your time everyone.

Comment: @kamal: How about sharing your solution?

Comment: @Gumbo check the update i have made.

Comment: @kamal, please post the solution you figured out as an answer, and mark it as accepted. That way other users will know that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php
$fragment = '<p>What a mighty fine <a href="blah">da';
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($fragment,array('show-body-only'=>true),'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
?>
```

enable `php_tidy extension` in localhost through php.ini and it works.